# Navigation bar moves along on scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a navigation bar and set of ul li elemts added.when the li elemtens are more the scrollbar is added.

But the navigation header moves along with scroll.How to make navigation bar be fixed at same position and make only li elements to move on scroll

```css
.file-info
{

height: 80vh;
background-color: white;
overflow:scroll;
 width:100%; 
position: relative;
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-6 file-info">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#view" class="nav-link active " data-toggle="tab">Report View</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#datamodel-view" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Datamodel View</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="view">
                <ul class="end-info" id = 'menu'>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li><li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
             </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.nav{position:fixed;}` to your css:

```css
.file-info{
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: white;
  overflow:scroll;
  width:100%; 
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
.nav{position:fixed;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-6 file-info">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#view" class="nav-link active " data-toggle="tab">Report View</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#datamodel-view" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Datamodel View</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="view">
                <ul class="end-info" id = 'menu'>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li><li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
             </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: when I tried to add li elements through jquery the li elements are being added behind the navigation bar at top.I mean they are added where my container starts not after the navigation bar if position: fixed is given

Comment: You might need to put a `margin-top: __px` (or padding-top) on the container that is partly overlapped by the fixed nav bar. Since the nav bar will always be there, this is a normal procedure. You can find out how many pixels to add to the margin via DevTools *(Right-Click on nav bar, choose Inspect Element) - in left pane click on the nav UL, in right side click on "Computed" tab and look at the height value)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the overflow on either the tab-content or the .tab-pane not on the parent div -

```css
.file-info {
 background-color: white;
 width:100%; 
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
 overflow: hidden
}


.tab-pane {
 height: 80vh;
 overflow-y:auto;
 overflow-x: hidden
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="col-sm-6 file-info">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#view" class="nav-link active " data-toggle="tab">Report View</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#datamodel-view" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Datamodel View</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="view">
                <ul class="end-info" id = 'menu'>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li><li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
             </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.file-info
{

height: 80vh;
background-color: white;
overflow:scroll;
 width:100%; 
position: relative;
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
.nav-tabs{
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-6 file-info">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#view" class="nav-link active " data-toggle="tab">Report View</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#datamodel-view" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Datamodel View</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="view">
                <ul class="end-info" id = 'menu'>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li><li>Sales</li>
                  <li>Sales</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
             </div>
     </div>
```

use

```
.nav-tabs{
   position:fixed;
 }
```

this will keep the nav-tabs class to a fixed position and where remaining all are scrollable. read here more about CSS [positions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)